# How can i force an automatic login in a html file from session data?

Tags: php, html

Im creating a portal, that once an user logs into the portal, they will have 2 buttons (for testlink page and splunk page) to be redirected to. i want this one login to persist...

in teslink i manged to do so, because the page was in php so i just captured the page, but in splunk, its just html. is there a way to capture the session data or post insto the login page automatically? I need it to log in automatically when redirected to that page with the session user and session pass variables. Any ideas??

Comment: In pure HTML you can't do it. You need to use PHP. Pure HTML is always static page. Maybe you can use JavaScript - but this will be totally not secure.

Comment: javascript could run in pure html? and could it get session data?

Comment: with ajax or any other way to get sessions informations... so basically it will be php